# Filter between two dates not working in Azure table storage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have one table in azure storage and I want to have a filter by two dates (Between two dates) on **ActionDate** column
please look at this image link that represent the table in azure storage.
[Here is my Azure table storage structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fuYT.jpg)

this is my snippet code I have no idea what is the problem exactly which not return any rows

```
Public storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DataConnectionString"))
Public tableClient As CloudTableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient()
Public table As CloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("tblLogs")




    Dim startDate = DateTime.Parse(txtdate1.Text)
    Dim endDate = DateTime.Parse(txtdate2.Text)



    If startDate.ToString() <> "" And endDate.ToString() <> "" Then


        Dim querySelectedDates = TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ActionDate", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, startDate),
                                                           TableOperators.[And],
                                                           TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ActionDate", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, endDate))


        Dim query As TableQuery(Of azTableLogging) = New TableQuery(Of azTableLogging)().Where(querySelectedDates)


        Dim alldatatable As New DataTable

        alldatatable.Columns.Add("UserFullName", GetType(String))
        alldatatable.Columns.Add("UserEmail", GetType(String))
        alldatatable.Columns.Add("ActionDate", GetType(String))
        alldatatable.Columns.Add("ActionType", GetType(String))
        alldatatable.Columns.Add("UrlName", GetType(String))



        For Each message As azTableLogging In table.ExecuteQuery(query)


            alldatatable.Rows.Add(message.UserFullName, message.UserEmail, message.ActionDate, message.UrlName)

        Next

        rpuserlog.DataSource = alldatatable
        rpuserlog.DataBind()


    End If
```

Comment: Please post some input for `txtdate1.Text` and `txtdate2.Text`, have you checked that the parsed DateTime values are what you expected?

Comment: Both txtdate1 and txtdate2 are type date when I select two dates I got this 

startDate=  5/1/2020 12:00:00 AM

endDate= 11/3/2020 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Try it using `GenerateFilterConditionForDate`

Comment: COuld you please tell me data type of ActionDate in Azure table?

Comment: @jim-xu ActionDate data type is string  `Public Property ActionDate As String`

Comment: @404 I tried `GenerateFilterConditionForDate ` it doesn't work I mean there is no result.

Comment: @JuniorDev sorry; I assumed you used the `DateTime` type for your dates. Unfortunately your filters will never work with your current date format. Reason is that the filter does it interpret it as a date. As example: since `1` comes before `2` a date starting with `1` will be less or equal to one starting with a `2`. Thus a date like `1/2/2020` will show up if you filter less or equal to `2/2/2019`.